# How can I access the data of a PHP Laravel Collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

402/5000
I have this collection of data, from a table called "Actividades", that has a many to many relationship with another table called "Estrategias".

My data collection has 3 Actividades that share a Estrategia.

So my problem is how I can show in the html the attribute "descripcion" of the strategy that is in the three Actividades.

the image shows the data collection

[image]

This is what I have in the controller

```
$actividades = Actividad::orderby('id', 'ASC')->with('estrategias')->where('evidencia_id', $evidenciaid)->get();
    dd($actividades);
```

This is what I tried to do in the html

```
    @foreach($actividades as $actividad)
      <div>
        {{$actividad->estrategias->descripcion}}}
      </div>
    @endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of relationship you have between `$activedades` and `estrategias` ? is it one-to-one or one-to-many ??

Comment: It looks like a one-to-many, so you'd need another foreach loop for `$actividad->estrategias`

Comment: From what i can see in the image, estrategias is another collection, so you should make another nested loop to access the attributes of each object in the collection. but to write an answer, better show us how you define relationships

Comment: @alithedeveloper is many to many

Answer (score 0):

`estrategias` is an array of instances of `Estrategia`

```php
@foreach($actividades as $actividad)
  <div>
    @if(isset($actividad->estrategias[0]){{$actividad->estrategias[0]->descripcion}}}@endif
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture you have posted, it looks like you need to loop over the `estragias` collection as well

```
@foreach($actividades as $actividad)
      <div>
        @foreach($actividad->estrategias as $estragias)
           {{ estrategias->descripcion }}
        @endforeach
      </div>
    @endforeach
```

This should fix it for you

Comment: the activities share strategies, with this code the strategies are shown repeatedly,
Is it possible that the strategies shown are not repeated?

Comment: @Talked, What kind of relationship you have between `activity` and `estragias` but you can always have `one-to-one` relationship or get `unique` results from collection

Answer (score 0):

If has one relationship

```
@foreach($actividades as $actividad)
      <div>

          {{$actividad->estrategias->descripcion }}

      </div>
    @endforeach
```

If has many relationship

```
@foreach($actividades as $actividad)
      <div>
        @foreach($actividad->estrategias as $estragias)
           {{ estrategias->descripcion }}
        @endforeach
      </div>
    @endforeach
```